# UNION with order by in HQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

How can I do this `Mysql` query in `HQL` :

```
select id , date from TABLE_1
union all
select id , date from TABLE_2

order by date asc
```

I know that the alternative to `union` is to make two separate requests but i want the `union` with the `order by` because it will help me a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `separate` the query to two query and then `combine` tow result lists into one and finally `sort` the final list with a `Comparator`:

```
Query query1 = session.createQuery("select t.id,t.dt from Table1 t");
Query query2 = session.createQuery("select t.id,t.dt from Table2 t");

List list1= query1.list();
List list2= query2.list();

list1.add(list2);


Collections.sort(list1, new Comparator<TABLE>(){
       public int compare (Table t1, Table t2){
           return t1.getDate().compareTo(t2.getDate());
       }
});
```

---

**EDIT(after comments):** in case of `UNION` (when query use `UNION` instead of union all and also without a `Order By`) we can use a HashSet:

```
Query query1 = session.createQuery("select t.id,t.dt from Table1 t");
Query query2 = session.createQuery("select t.id,t.dt from Table2 t");

List list1= query1.list();
List list2= query2.list();

list1.add(list2);

HashSet uniqueResult = new HashSet(list1);
```

Comment: finally it works without your last line because `list1` is sorted well no need to collect them all in a `HashSet` because it lost the sort ... can you please edit your answer

Comment: Yes of course, I just added it in case of `unique result (UNION)` and for `UNION ALL` it does not need to use a HashSet

Comment: oh, yes you are right(I didn't noticed the hashset may broke the order) so let me to edit the answer and remove last line.

Comment: now it's good but the use of HashSet must be before the sort i think.

Comment: it's a separate way for specific solution I mean using HashSet is good only when `UNIQUE` is important and `Order by` is not, because HashSet does not guarantee any sort and am not sure about sorting a HashSet of entities on base of specific fields. and `yes` it should be before sort (instead of it)

Comment: yes but the question is about sorting so in your answer you have to explain it so the future people that will face this problem knows the difference.

Comment: yes you are right, and I think now the answer is clear (specially with our comments), if you don't think just tell me to edit what you think is wrong.

Comment: yes with comments is clear but you know , people don't see in the comments if the answer is accepted they try it directly .. anyway it's my case :)

Comment: To sort using Java isn't a solution when you're rcovering thousands of elements and SQL is much more agile to do this, so this solution isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses needed -- What you have is

```
( select id , date from TABLE_1 )
union all
( select id , date from TABLE_2
order by date asc )
```

What you want is

```
( select id , date from TABLE_1 )
union all
( select id , date from TABLE_2 )
order by date asc
```

Comment: no it works without Parentheses in `MySQL` but i want the query in `HQL`.